# 'OptionMenu' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

Python 3.9

Windows 10
VSCode

Hey guys, I'm making a weather converter in tkinter for a school project and neither google nor my teacher can figure this out.

Whenever I put a value into both dropdown menus and hit convert I get the error:
'OptionMenu' has no attribute 'get'

Here's my code;
The key areas are the Check_Input definition and the menus from lines 68-97.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

# Dropdown menu options
Temp_Options = ["Celsius", "Fahrenheit", "Kelvin"]

root = Tk()
root.title("The World\'s Best Temperature Converter")
root.geometry("575x250")
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')


# Checks what units were input
def Check_Input():
    print (Input_Value.get)
    if Input_Value.get == "Celsius":
        print("Input Recieved = Celsius")
        Celsius()
    if Input_Value.get == "Fahrenheit":
        print("Input Recieved = Fahrenheit")
        Fahrenheit()
    if Input_Value.get == "Kelvin":
        Kelvin()
        print("Input Recieved = Kelvin")
    else:
        print("Check Input Failed")


# Convert FROM Celsius
def Celsius():
    Temp = User_Input.get()
    if Output_Value.get == "Celsius":
        Answer = ((Temp * 9/5) + 32)
    if Output_Value.get == "Fahrenheit":
        Answer = (Temp - 32 * (9/5))
    if Output_Value.get == "Kelvin":
        Answer = (Temp - 273.15)
    Final_Answer = Label(root, text=Answer)
    Final_Answer.grid(row=3, column=1)


# Convert FROM Fahrenheit
def Fahrenheit():
    Temp = User_Input.get()
    if Output_Value.get == "Celsius":
        Answer = ((Temp * 9/5) + 32)
    if Output_Value.get == "Fahrenheit":
        Answer = (Temp - 32 * (9/5))
    if Output_Value.get == "Kelvin":
        Answer = (Temp - 273.15)
    Final_Answer = Label(root, text=Answer)
    Final_Answer.grid(row=3, column=1)


# Convert FROM Kelvin
def Kelvin():
    Temp = User_Input.get()
    if Output_Value.get == "Celsius":
        Answer = ((Temp * 9/5) + 32)
    if Output_Value.get == "Fahrenheit":
        Answer = (Temp - 32 * (9/5))
    if Output_Value.get == "Kelvin":
        Answer = (Temp - 273.15)
    Final_Answer = Label(root, text=Answer)
    Final_Answer.grid(row=3, column=1)


# Choose Default for Input options
Input_Value = StringVar(root)
Input_Value.set("Select Input")

# Input Options Menu
Input_Value = OptionMenu(
    root, Input_Value, *Temp_Options)
Input_Value.config(width=9)
Input_Value.grid(row=1, column=0)


# Chose Default for Output Options
Output_Value = StringVar(root)
Output_Value.set("Select Output")

# Output options menu
Output_Value = OptionMenu(
    root, Output_Value, *Temp_Options)
Output_Value.config(width=9)
Output_Value.grid(row=1, column=2)


# Text Input Box
User_Input = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=10)
User_Input.grid(row=1, column=1)


# Button
Convert = Button(root, text="Convert", command=Check_Input)
Convert.grid(row=1, column=3)


root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance, sorry if the question is stupid.

Comment: You have used same name `Input_Value` for `StringVar` and `OptionMenu`.  Same for `Output_Value`.

Comment: You're a lifesaver dude, this completely fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

As acw1668 said in the comments

I was using the same name for StringVar and OptionMenu.

Changing it throughout the project fixed everything.

Also I'm now realising that the math portion of my code is all messed up but that's something I can fix on my own.